# Labeling buttons

Tags: buttons, labels, content

How do you think buttons/actions should be labeled.

Let's say we have an entity called "Review".

On this review there are many actions. You can Cancel, Stop, Reassign, etc..

There will be many reviews in a table format.

Which way do you feel is the best way to label the actions?

**Option 1:**
Cancel, Stop, Reassign

**Option 2**
Cancel Review, Stop Review, Reassign Review

Is option 2 redundant?

Comment: Are there any other items in the screen or user's mindset that might give Cancel, Stop and Reassign a different meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to consider:

- **Is the action understood?**
- **Is the element the action is referring to understood?**

These depend on the context of the actual page, the layout, the context of the user, etc.

**You might need to combine buttons that have only the action name with others that also need the object name**.

- Both points are clear: your Option 1 should be enough.
- Only the first point is clear: you might want to include the object name, like in your Option 2.
- Only the second point is clear: reconsider the name of the action rather than if including the object name.
- None of the points are clear: reconsider the name of the action, the layout, the context, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 might be redundant depending on the simplicity or complexity of the form.
If you still need to tell the user things like in option 2, consider using a fieldset with the title "Review actions" or something like that to group your buttons, then labelling them as in option 1.